# HTML5 video (MP4) autoplay not working on Android

Tags: android, html, video, html5-video, mp4

I am trying to autoplay a video (MP4) in the browser on an Android device (Android version 5.1.1). If I use the MP4 video in the Fiddle below it always autoplays on my mobile device:
https://jsfiddle.net/yLgj8jd2/

However for some reason my MP4 video most of the times does not autoplay on an Android device (when I try it 10 times it autoplays maybe 2 times) which makes me believe that the problems is perhaps within the settings of my MP4 file. I have created a Fiddle which includes my MP4 video:
https://jsfiddle.net/rhoghsde/3/

```
<video autoplay muted playsinline>
<source src="http://mockingbird.travel/media/video/location/es/city/52/barcelona_240p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Why does my MP4 video not autoplay in the browser on an Android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suspicion would be that the moov atom in your video is not at the start. If you are using ffmpeg to encode the video please see the faststart. flag.https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Comment: Thanks, I am using Handbrake to edit videos and checking 'Web Optimized' seems to have solved the autoplay problem (which seems to be the equivalent of faststart, but correct me if i am wrong).